# Display only the first of <h1> that has a different name

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

The headings are dynamically obtained. The structure currently looks like this:

```
<h1>HEADING CONTENT 1</h1>
some content
<h1>HEADING CONTENT 1</h1>
some content
<h1>HEADING CONTENT 1</h1>
some content
<h1>HEADING CONTENT 2</h1>
some content
<h1>HEADING CONTENT 2</h1>
some content
```

I only need to display the first instance of each heading. How do I do that?

EDIT: I'm sorry, I'm currently at a different PC. I will as soon as I can.

Comment: what is your real html structure ?

Comment: You only want to hide the headings, but all content should be shown, right?

Comment: "The structure currently looks like this:" If it does, that's some messed up HTML....

Comment: @user2772219 have you tried any of the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 7):

if your headings are all actually siblings as in your structure, you could use the general sibling selector/combinator `~` and thus `display: none` all the repeated headings

```
h1 ~ h1, 
h2 ~ h2 {
   display: none;
}
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Evuhr/

---

**After your update**:

If the headings are all `<h1>` and you have to check the text contained, you need to use javascript/jQuery like so

```
$(function() {
  var title = ""
  $('h1').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() !== title) {
        title = $(this).text();
     } 
     else {
       $(this).hide();  
     }    
  });  
});
```

Example on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FBltb

Comment: +1 So how does the the `~` works actually? I mean why is the first one left out?

Comment: Because it matches an element that comes after an element, and the first one doesn't come after an element while the rest do.

Comment: `E ~ F` matches all `F` elements siblings of `E` (and defined after `E` in the markup)

Comment: Considering the example I gave in my original post, if I use this, it will hide all headings after "Header 1". I also need to display the first "Header 2".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. They are all <h1> they only differ in content. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2772219 I've prepared another example to fit your new question

Answer (score 0):

This might work too, even if im unsure, CSS is not my strongest side.

```
h1, h2 {
    display:none;
}

h1:first-of-type, h2:first-of-type {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Im so happy, no reputation will be lost this day! :D

Answer (score 0):

## Updated

If you are using same `<h1>` header tag and want to show first based on innertext you can use `:contains` and `.first()` to get the required result:

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/237Zy/)

**CSS** first hide all `h1`s

```
h1{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("h1").each(function(){
    $("h1:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").first().css('display','block');
});
```

---

**jQuery with better ops/sec:**

```
var $h1s = $("h1");
$h1s.each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).data('validated')) {
        return;
    }
    $h1s.filter(":contains('" + $(this).text() + "')").data('validated', true).first().show();
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gvae7/)

Comment: This is looking like the correct answer. I will try in a few hours and get back to you.

Comment: Ofcourse try yourself and verify if its working for you.If you have any doubt you can ask